# linked in data scraper in node.js

Tags: node.js

In my code linkedInProfile is not a function that error display in console how to solve that error???

```
var linkedInProfile = require('linkedin-public-profile');
app.get('/api/webapi/:version/users', function(req,res){
    var url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/bansridamani/';
    linkedInProfile(url).then(profile => {
      console.log(profile);
    });
    var request = require('request-promise');
    request(url)
    .then(html => linkedInProfile(html))
    .then(profile => {
      console.log(profile);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are using dead repo for scraping public data of linkedin profiles [linkedin-public-profile](https://github.com/julianbei/linkedin-public-profile).

And please check the api documentations of linkedin REST API to [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api).

Also check the linkedin API console to [here](https://apigee.com/resources/linkedin) for testing.

Hope this will help you!